# automate couchbase configuration in docker

Tags: docker, couchbase

I am very new on docker and couchbase. I want to make some initial configuration in couchbase. I used this script for setting admin user and password (all lines same) 
https://github.com/madhur/couchbase-docker/blob/master/couchbase/configure-node.sh

When I go localhost:8091 I didnt login with `username=Administrator -d password=password` like in configure-node.sh. But I can login `username=Administrator -d password=123456` which I set this username and password when I fisrt running my applicaiton. Now I deleted couchbase images and I am trying to login new password but I didnt. Why still old password is valid and I cant login with new?

Here is my all Dockerfile content:

```
FROM couchbase/server
COPY configure-node.sh /opt/couchbase
CMD ["/opt/couchbase/configure-node.sh"]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml related part which I added :

```
couchbase-db:
    build: couchbase/couchbase-conf
```

So I did only these changings.

When I run `docker-compose up -d couchbase-db` I am taking this:

```
Creating network "dev_default" with the default driver
Building couchbase-db
Step 1 : FROM couchbase/server
latest: Pulling from couchbase/server
6c953ac5d795: Already exists
3eed5ff20a90: Already exists
f8419ea7c1b5: Already exists
51900bc9e720: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists
d2b32431ebaf: Already exists
6df065d46e65: Already exists
35c916dbd640: Already exists
ef4d6b32517b: Already exists
ac899008ccff: Already exists
a38e2a84ca14: Already exists
009f47caeb08: Already exists
8567214b778f: Already exists
Digest:            sha256:72ed5cb40465e65c8d9cbf22a0dedc081ae0453e5b121ae4618c7436c70478c7
Status: Downloaded newer image for couchbase/server:latest
---> 97d69bb5e7f4
Step 2 : COPY configure-node.sh /opt/couchbase
---> beaa25387e4e
Removing intermediate container f1352ae8478a
Step 3 : CMD /opt/couchbase/configure-node.sh
 ---> Running in be5614f4702d
 ---> 0354f9e07af7
Removing intermediate container be5614f4702d
Successfully built 0354f9e07af7
WARNING: Image for service couchbase-db was built because it did         not already exist.To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose      build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating dev_couchbase-db_1
```

Then I am looking couchbase logs with : `docker-compose logs -f couchbase-db`. And I am getting this:

```
Attaching to dev_couchbase-db_1
couchbase-db_1  | Starting Couchbase Server -- Web UI available at      http://<ip>:8091
couchbase-db_1  | {error_logger,{{2016,8,18},   {19,15,49}},"global_trace:~n~p",[{loop_the_locker,{multi,[],[],   [],'nonode@nohost',false,false}}]}
couchbase-db_1  | *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
couchbase-db_1  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed       Time    Time     Time  Current
couchbase-db_1  |                                  Dload  Upload       Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- -    -:--:--     0* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8091 (#0)
couchbase-db_1  | > POST /pools/default HTTP/1.1
couchbase-db_1  | > User-Agent: curl/7.40.0-DEV
couchbase-db_1  | > Host: 127.0.0.1:8091
couchbase-db_1  | > Accept: */*
couchbase-db_1  | > Content-Length: 36
couchbase-db_1  | > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
couchbase-db_1  | > 
couchbase-db_1  | } [36 bytes data]
couchbase-db_1  | * upload completely sent off: 36 out of 36 bytes
couchbase-db_1  | < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
couchbase-db_1  | < WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Couchbase Server    Admin / REST"
couchbase-db_1  | < Server: Couchbase Server
couchbase-db_1  | < Pragma: no-cache
couchbase-db_1  | < Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 19:16:48 GMT
couchbase-db_1  | < Content-Length: 0
couchbase-db_1  | < Cache-Control: no-cache
couchbase-db_1  | < 
100    36    0     0  100    36      0  30252 --:--:-- --:--:-- -    -:--:-- 36000
couchbase-db_1  | * Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
couchbase-db_1  | *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
couchbase-db_1  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed       Time    Time     Time  Current
couchbase-db_1  |                                  Dload  Upload       Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- -  -:--:--     0* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8091 (#0)
couchbase-db_1  | > POST /node/controller/setupServices HTTP/1.1
couchbase-db_1  | > User-Agent: curl/7.40.0-DEV
couchbase-db_1  | > Host: 127.0.0.1:8091
couchbase-db_1  | > Accept: */*
couchbase-db_1  | > Content-Length: 26
couchbase-db_1  | > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
couchbase-db_1  | > 
couchbase-db_1  | } [26 bytes data]
couchbase-db_1  | * upload completely sent off: 26 out of 26 bytes
couchbase-db_1  | < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
couchbase-db_1  | < WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Couchbase Server     Admin / REST"
couchbase-db_1  | < Server: Couchbase Server
couchbase-db_1  | < Pragma: no-cache
couchbase-db_1  | < Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 19:16:48 GMT
couchbase-db_1  | < Content-Length: 0
couchbase-db_1  | < Cache-Control: no-cache
couchbase-db_1  | < 
100    26    0     0  100    26      0  20967 --:--:-- --:--:-- -  -:--:-- 26000
couchbase-db_1  | * Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
couchbase-db_1  | *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
couchbase-db_1  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed       Time    Time     Time  Current
couchbase-db_1  |                                  Dload  Upload      Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8091 (#0)
couchbase-db_1  | > POST /settings/web HTTP/1.1
couchbase-db_1  | > User-Agent: curl/7.40.0-DEV
couchbase-db_1  | > Host: 127.0.0.1:8091
couchbase-db_1  | > Accept: */*
couchbase-db_1  | > Content-Length: 50
couchbase-db_1  | > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
couchbase-db_1  | > 
couchbase-db_1  | } [50 bytes data]
couchbase-db_1  | * upload completely sent off: 50 out of 50 bytes
couchbase-db_1  | < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
couchbase-db_1  | < WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Couchbase Server    Admin / REST"
couchbase-db_1  | < Server: Couchbase Server
couchbase-db_1  | < Pragma: no-cache
couchbase-db_1  | < Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 19:16:48 GMT
couchbase-db_1  | < Content-Length: 0
couchbase-db_1  | < Cache-Control: no-cache
couchbase-db_1  | < 
100    50    0     0  100    50      0  19357 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 25000
couchbase-db_1  | * Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
couchbase-db_1  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed       Time    Time     Time  Current
couchbase-db_1  |                                  Dload  Upload      Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    73    0     0  100    73      0    888 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   901
couchbase-db_1  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed       Time    Time     Time  Current
couchbase-db_1  |                                  Dload  Upload      Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    70    0     0  100    70      0   5943 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6363
couchbase-db_1  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed      Time    Time     Time  Current
couchbase-db_1  |                                  Dload  Upload      Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    28    0     0  100    28      0   5261 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5600
couchbase-db_1  | HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
couchbase-db_1  | WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Couchbase Server    Admin / REST"
couchbase-db_1  | Server: Couchbase Server
couchbase-db_1  | Pragma: no-cache
couchbase-db_1  | Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 19:16:48 GMT
couchbase-db_1  | Content-Length: 0
couchbase-db_1  | Cache-Control: no-cache
couchbase-db_1  | 
couchbase-db_1  | Type: , Master:  clause. In the asynchronous    mode, CREATE PRIMARY INDEX starts a task to create the primary index and returns as soon as the task is queued for execution. The full   inOUCHBASE_MASTER
couchbase-db_1  | /entrypoint.sh couchbase-server
```

Here is my project folder structure part related docker:

[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vx2R.png)

Comment: Its not clear what are you trying to accomplish. Are you just trying to change the username/password? The original `configure-node.sh` script was published at https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/tree/master/couchbase. Feel free to use that instead.